# Positive solution to a Linear system of Equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I have the following system of linear equations $$A\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{u}$$ where $$A=(a_{ij}),\quad a_{ij}=a^{p_iq_j},\ 0<a<1$$ where $p_i,q_j\forall  0\le i,j\le N-1$ are non-negative real numbers that I can choose. Also $\mathbf{u>0}$ is given i.e. each component of $\mathbf{u}$ is $>0$. Then my question is under what conditions upon $p_i,q_j$ I can have a solution for $\mathbf{v}$, and can I have a solution such that $\mathbf{v>0}$?

**Update:** Let me relax the conditions on $p_i, q_j$ a little bit more. Let, $q_j=j-1\quad 0\le j\le N-1$ and $p_i$ are in increasing order i.e. $p_0<p_1<\cdots \ p_{N-1}$. Also I have $u_1>u_2>\cdots \ >u_{N-1}$. Then we have the matrix equation as $$\mathbf{Mv}={u}$$ where $M=(m_{ij})$ is a Vandermonde matrix with $\displaystyle m_{ij}=a^{(i-1)p_{j-1}}$. Now the question is how to choose $p_j$'s such that $\mathbf{v>0}$ for the given $\mathbf{u>0}$?

Comment: What do you mean by $\bf{u} > 0$?  This is a vector.  Each component is > 0?

Comment: Yes @Euler....IS_ALIVE, that's what I mean.

Comment: @Samrat Mukhopadhyay:  are the $p_i$, $q_j$ supposed to be integers?  Positive integers?

Comment: @RobertLewis, $p_i,q_j\in \mathbb{R^+}$.

Comment: @Samrat Mukhopadhyay:  OK, thanks.

Comment: Do you want $p_i,q_j$ to be such that for ANY $u > 0$, you can always find a solution $v > 0$?  Or do you just have one value of $u$, and you want to know all choices of $p_i,q_j$ that give a solution $v > 0$ just for the one choice of $u$?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find $p_i,q_j$ such that for any $u > 0$ (component-wise) you can always find a solution $v > 0$, then it is impossible.  Note that for any choice of values for $p_i,q_j$, your linear transformation $A$ will carry the first orthant $S$ (set of all vectors with positive entries) to a cone which is a strict subset of $S$.  So each $u \in S - AS$ will not have a solution $v > 0$.  If you just have one given choice of $u > 0$ and you want to know when you can find $v > 0$ for that particular $u$, then it's more tricky.

Comment: Why is the solution set a strict subset of $S$?

Comment: Because $AS$ is definitely a subset of $S$, and it's a (polyhedral) cone generated by the columns of $A$, and the only way for two polyhedral cones to be equal is if they have the same generating vectors, so $A$ would have to be the identity matrix in order for $AS = S$. But that's impossible because your $A$ has all positive entries.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Actually I have a set of data for vector $u$ which is positive, and I want to find $v$ for that. So I should better ask the question for particular $u$ as you suggested. Thanks.